# Oracle/SQL - Combining counts from 'unrelated' unrelated tables

Tags: sql, oracle, count, union

Let's assume I two tables `GOOD` and `BAD` that stores records for widget production.  My tables look like this

```
Widget      Good
----------------
Widget A    Y
Widget A    Y
Widget B    Y

Widget      Bad
----------------
Widget A    Y
Widget B    Y
```

I have these two basic queries

```
select count(*) as good from table_good where widget = 'Widget A' and Good = 'Y'
select count(*) as bad from table_bad where widget = 'Widget A' and Bad = 'Y'
```

These would result in two tables like this

```
good
----
2

bad
---
1
```

I would like to combine these into a single query where I would get back a table with a single record that looks like this

```
good    bad
-----------
2       1
```

Can someone point me how to do this.  I thought doing a union and setting up fake columns in the other tables selects would do it, but I got the right table schema back, but had two seperate records.

Thanks!

Comment: @Andriy M - You were right, I did some testing and the `GROUP BY` did not work as I anticipated with that query.  Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS good 
        FROM   table_good 
        WHERE  widget = 'Widget A' 
               AND good = 'Y') AS good, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS bad 
        FROM   table_bad 
        WHERE  widget = 'Widget A' 
               AND bad = 'Y')  AS bad 
FROM   dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.widget,B.widget) AS Widget, COUNT(G.*) AS Good, COUNT(B.*) AS Bad
FROM table_good G
FULL OUTER JOIN table_bad B
ON G.widget = B.widget AND A.Good = B.Bad
WHERE (G.widget = 'Widget A' OR B.Widget = 'Widget A') 
AND (G.Good = 'Y' OR B.Good = 'Y')
```