# Problem: Getting different results from SUM queries

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the below query:

```
select SUM(t1.total_amount) as one, SUM(t2.total_amount) as two
from table1 t1, table2 t2;
```

I get these results:

```
ONE     TWO
2000    3000
```

But when I run this query:

```
select SUM(t1.total_amount) as one table1 t1;
```

I get this result:

```
ONE
50
```

It looks like the result from the first query is incorrect. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing this:

```
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

you're actually cross joining both tables, resulting in a cartesian product (every row in t1 is combined with every row in t2).

You're probably missing a JOIN condition:

```
select sum(t1.total_amount), sum(t2.total_amount)
from t1 join t2 on t1.[???] = t2.[???]
```

EDIT:

based on your comment, it looks like you want a union of these two separate queries
    select 't1', sum(total_amount) from t1
    union 
    select 't2', sum(total_amount) from t2

This will show the sums in two rows instead of columns, but it's the easiest way AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually having a hard time to get this working. I should maybe clarify what I'm trying to do here. I want to display the sum of 2 columns from 2 different tables next to each other so I can compare them (i.e. sum of column A from table X next to sum of column B from table Y). I tried the above query but I don't understand why I should join the tables and how. Because these two tables are not anyhow related.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, did you google for answers before writing the question?
Google "+oracle +combining tables" gives a good answer rightaway: 
[Oracle/SQL - Combining counts from 'unrelated' unrelated tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721040/oracle-sql-combining-counts-from-unrelated-unrelated-tables)

Since you indicate that the table are unrelated, just with similar data,
a UNION is probably the nicer solution.
But along the lines of the prior question above you can select the partial results and then combine them with the ever willing the donate "select from dual" (non) context.

Example:

```
select COUNT(*), SUM(X) from SOME_TABLE;

COUNT(*)     SUM(X)
----------   ----------
57           6450

select COUNT(*), SUM(X) from OTHER_TABLE;

COUNT(*)     SUM(X)
----------   ----------
315          15165

select ( select SUM(X) from SOME_TABLE) as ONE,
       ( select SUM(X) from OTHER_TABLE) as TWO from dual;

ONE        TWO
---------- ----------
6450       15165
```